# Review of this AES-128 CBC example with password-based encryption

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, salt, initialization-vector

I need some help validating the below code snippet for Java AES encryption with CBC, PKCS5Padding and IV.

I tested the code and was able to encrypt and decrypt. I have a few queries as described below.

1. Where should the password be stored as a good convention?
2. Is the way of appending/retrieving salt and IV bytes to the ciphetext fine?
3. Any other comments highly appreciated, thanks!

```
public class Encryption {

    private static int iterations = 65536;
    private static int keySize = 128;
    private static char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
    private static String algorithm= "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";


    private static final String SEPARATOR = "~";


     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {

         String filePath = "test.xml";

         String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));

         String encrMesg = encrypt(fileContent);

         System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypt(encrMesg)); 

         System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decrypt(encrMesg)); 
     }


    public static String encrypt(String plaintext) throws Exception {


        byte[] saltBytes = getSalt().getBytes();

        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, saltBytes, iterations, keySize);
        SecretKey secretKey = skf.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretSpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretSpec);
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

        byte[] ivBytes = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(String.valueOf(plaintext).getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(ivBytes)+SEPARATOR+DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(saltBytes)
        +SEPARATOR+DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cipherText);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(encryptedText);

        String[] encryptedArr = encryptedText.split(SEPARATOR);

        byte[] ivBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(new String(encryptedArr[0]));

        byte[] salt = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(new String(encryptedArr[1]));

        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(new String(encryptedArr[2]));

        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, keySize);
        SecretKey secretKey = skf.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretSpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretSpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;

        try {
            decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String(decryptedTextBytes);

    }

    public static String getSalt() throws Exception {

        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] salt = new byte[20];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        return new String(salt);
    }

}
```

Comment: The best place to store the password is the human brain. That's the whole point of using a password in the first place. If you store it on the machine it is better to store the binary key in a secure way.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the libraries that do this well? [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor) and [this one](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto) come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries

> Where should the password be stored as a good convention?

Symmetric keys should go preferably to a vault. Otherwise they should go on a keystore, but then you have the issue of securing the keystore password.

> Is the way of appending/retrieving Salt and IV bytes to the Cipher
>   text is fine?

Salt should be generated with:

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
```

Otherwise you are using weaker entropy pools (i.e. /dev/urandom in linux) to generate your secure numbers, and that leads to weak keys that can be more easily broken.

> Any other comments highly appreciated, thanks!

You should consistently use the same encoding when dealing with String conversion, i.e., `.getBytes("UTF-8")` to avoid issues. You don't use it when converting the salt for example.

Comment: Private keys are as hard to secure. Asymmetric encryption is very slow compared to symmetric encryption and the data length is limited to less than the key size. Generally data is encrypted with a symmetric method such as AES and keys are encrypted with asymmetric encryption. Note that TLS encrypts the data with symmetric encryption.

Comment: Virtually all data is encrypted with symmetric encryption. Given an RSA 2048-bit key the data limitation is less than 256-bytes, for an 256-bit EC key the data limitation is less than 32-bytes. With AES there is essentially no data length limitation. Symmetric encryption is the work horse of encryption. In the case of iOS all the file system data is encrypted with symmetric encryption: AES.

Comment: Note: The last paragraph WRT symmetric and asymmetric keys has been deleted from the answer as has the related comment.

Comment: Yes I am trying to keep this as relevant for the OP as possible, and trying to learn in the process. Thank you for your remarks in making the answer better and more relevant.